# creating new field for certain records in miniMongo

Tags: meteor, minimongo

This Meteor client code tries to create `selected` fields an sets their values to true, the miniMongo is not being updated.
There are few items in the `indexes` array.
 How can it be fixed? Thanks

```
let res = myColMini.update({
  index: {
    $in: [indexes]
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    selected: true
  }
}, {
  multi: true
});
console.log(res); //<--- 0
```

Comment: I believe the multi update is not supported in Meteor miniMongo. (I could be wrong but I have had a similar issue with multi insert)
the way to get around this is to loop through each document and update one at a time without multi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, `multi` is not supported on the client. Either run this update on the server or do:

```
myColMini.find({ index: { $in: [indexes] } }).forEach(function(m),{
  myColMini.update(m._id, $set: { selected: true } });
});
```